# Каким является обращение в представленном предложении? Распространенным или нераспространенным?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, обращение

«Природа-мать, когда б таких людей ты иногда не посылала миру, заглохла б нива жизни...» В данном случае обращение «Природа-мать» является распространенным или нераспространенным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определяемое слово и приложение нередко сливаются в **цельное сочетание – один член предложения** (княжна Марья, товарищ капитан, капитан Иванов, Волга-матушка, Иван-царевич, Аника-воин...), а иногда и в одно слово (диван-кровать, платье-костюм...). [Приложение как разновидность определения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/717-241_prilozhenie_kak_raznovidnost_opredeleniya.html)

В Вашем примере ПРИРОДА-МАТЬ - цельное сочетание. Обращение можно считать нераспространённым. Конечно, никаким членом предложения обращение не является.